# Defining a type-checking containerof macro without using compiler extensions

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer

The following is the quick and easy way to define the `containerof`
macro, using only standard C features:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#define containerof(ptr, type, member) \
((type *)((char *)(ptr)-offsetof(type, member)))
```

Another commonly found definition of the macro uses GNU C [statement
expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) to
provide additional type-checking:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#if __GNUC__+0 >= 3
#define containerof(ptr, type, member) ({ \
const __typeof__(((type *)0)->member) *containerof_memberptr_ = (ptr); \
(type *)((char *)(containerof_memberptr_)-offsetof(type, member)); })
#else
/* fallback */
#endif
```

My question is if there's a definition of the macro using only standard
C features that still checks the referenced type of the `ptr` argument
against the type of the `member` argument?

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with the following definition:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#define containerof(ptr, type, member) \
((type *)((char *)(0 ? &((type *)0)->member : (ptr))-offsetof(type, member)))
```

Any incompatible pointer passed as the `ptr` argument violates the
following constraint of the conditional operator (C90 **6.3.15
Conditional operator**):

> — both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of
> compatible types

I was hoping for such a violation to generate an error by default,
however GCC and clang only issue a warning and there doesn't seem to be
a specific `-Werror=...` option in GCC to turn the emitted warning into
an error.

> warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression

clang conveniently provides such an option called
`-Werror=pointer-type-mismatch`. And both GCC and clang support the
broad `-pedantic-errors` option that promotes the warning to an error as
well.

The standard requires a diagnostic message to be issued on constraint
violation (C90 **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**), but that doesn't mean the
compiler has to error out on non-compliant code.

In conclusion, it is possible to define a `containerof` macro that
doesn't rely on extensions to the language, yet still yields some
type-checking behavior, whether that is by issuing a mandatory
diagnostic message or a compilation error, given compiler support.

One other advantage of this definition (shared with the one lacking
type-checking) over the one using a GNU statement expression is that it
results in a constant expression usable in initializer contexts.

Comment: The `0 ?` is confusing. Why even include it?

Comment: The `0` as first operand of the conditional operator means only its third operand gets evaluated, in this case `(ptr)`. As an earlier (deleted?) comment noted we could as well write it as `1 ? (ptr) : &((type *)0)->member`, meaning only the second operand will get evaluated. The expression `&((type *)0)->member)` is just a way to construct a pointer to the type of `member`. Even if it's not evaluated, it is still checked for constraint violations. And that gets us the desired effect of a diagnostic if the type referenced by `ptr` and the type of `member` differ.

Comment: Doesn't that invoke undefined behavior, or is that only if it's evaluated?

Comment: Yes from what I remember `(type *)0)->member` is only undefined behavior if it's evaluated, though I don't remember how to derive that from requirements in the standard. Maybe just a proof by contradiction suffices? If an unevaluated expression yielded undefined behavior, even a commonly used expression such as `p && *p` would yield UB.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised with C, but I'm fairly confident that it's only if the expression is evaluated. If the expression is unconditionally evaluated then that's bad.